# iOS NSAutoLayoutConstraint: Not being set for views from storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have view, from a storyboard, in my ViewController. I try changing it's constraint using the code:

```
_viewFromStoryboard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *w = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_viewFromStoryboard attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *h = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_viewFromStoryboard attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_viewFromStoryboard attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_viewFromStoryboard attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];

[self.view addConstraints:@[w, h, centerX, centerY]];

[_viewFromStoryboard setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, but the constraints don't seem to  update.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should call LayoutIfNeeded method for update constraints...

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work

Comment: before update and after update calling this [self.view layoutIfNeeded] works for me

Answer (score 0):

Did the view have constraints setup in the storyboard already?

To change constraints already setup, I usually CTRL Drag from the constraint in story board into the class header and add an IBOutlet for each one I want to be able to change.

Then in the code, just change the constant value. That way you are changing the constraints already setup in storyboard.

I notice in your code you are also setting width and height to 0 it seems?

Comment: It's not set in the storyboard. That's how we set the widths to be equal for two views, isn't it?

Comment: Should this code not be in viewDidLoad? viewDidLayoutSubviews could get called multiple times and each time you will add copies of the constraints? Also have you remembered to call [super viewDidLayoutSubviews]?

Comment: viewDidLoad didn't seem to change affect things (even setting the position of the view didn't work in viewDidLoad).

Comment: What is it that you actually see when you run it? Is it 1) you see the view as it was in storyboard and its layout does not change or 2) you see nothing at all or 3) something else? Are there any constraint errors in the console log or any other errors?